# PDDocument loaded from encrypted pdf turns in encrypted one after calling save

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have encrypted pdf file which I load by `PDDocument.load` method, providing appropriate password.
After that I can use this `PDDocument` without any problems.
But if I call `save` on it, then this object suddenly contains encrypted content, and it is not usable after that (i.e. names of widgets are encrypted, etc.).

As a workaround I need to load this document once again.

Is there any better solution to save encrypted PDDcoument and use the same object without any interruption after calling `save`?

I use PdfBox 2.0.20.

Comment: You could call doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true), I have not fully understood the problem. I wonder if it is so that after saving encrypted, the PDF is no longer usable directly, and nobody has ever noticed because typically nobody would ever do that.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem - after `save` the document becomes useless and I need to "reload" it.
Calling `setAllSecurityToBeRemoved` is not an option because I want the document to be encrypted, but also I want to operate normally on its structure, as usual.

Comment: I suspect this is by design. One could mention it in the documentation / javadoc, but nobody reads documentation anyway :-(